# Control app from another app on another phone android

Tags: android

i want to build a child management application. i saw google `Family link`. It includes two apps one for parents, one for kids. App for parents can control the app on their children's phone. Does anyone have information on how to do this. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're trying to release two apps where one is for parents while the other one is for children, you'll most likely need a server to control it.

When parents want to apply parental control or see how the child is doing, they read/write data to/from the server. The child's app will then have to listen to the server for changes and peridically upload data to be shown in parent app when needed.

```
     Server
     /    \
 Parent  Child's
  app      app
```

---

If you're trying to create just one app that controls access to all other apps on the entire smartphone, you gotta look up on Android's SDK documentation if they allow anything like that, because forcefully interfering with another app is akin to hacking… which any rational operating systems would not allow. Unless the OS understands it as a parental control feature, which (based on my guess) the only way is through an officially provided API, if there is one. (So far I haven't come across anything like that in the docs, but it could be just because I missed it)

Otherwise, you might be better off desiging a launcher instead, as that would at least give you control over what apps can and cannot be opened.

---

*Also, it'd be nice if your question can be a little bit more specific/detailed. A long question that requires long time to read is still better than a short question that requires a long time to guess.*